# How to create metadata for jpeg images in xp

Tags: search, metadata, jpeg

I have an archive of Dilbert cartoons, and would like to organize them in a way, that I can find the one I need based on something on the order of a keyword search.

I am looking for suggestions on a reasonable way to accomplish that programatically.  I am leaning towards perl for an implemenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, being a fan of Perl, I would use Image::Metadata::JPEG. There are plenty of libraries for doing this type of thing, however.

If you're looking for a program to do it, I know photoshop can, and I'm sure there are other editors (The Gimp) that can as well.

I'm not sure if you're looking for a solution for searching through the images as well, but there are numerous photo archiving programs that will allow you to tag and search within them. Picassa comes to mind.

Comment: yes, i need to be able to find an image or set of images based on a text keyword